# How to take out parts of a string in swift

Tags: ios, string, swift

I want to take out a part of my String and afterwords I want to save it in a new String.

```
var key = "Optional("rFchd9DqwE")"
```

So my String equals now to Optional("rFchd9DqwE"). Now I want to take out the part rFchd9DqwE from this String and save it back in the variable "key". Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: you'll probably want to use a regex or substring. Here is a [post on substrings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28182441/swift-how-to-get-substring-from-start-to-last-index-of-character).

Comment: You should better figure out *why* you have "Optional" in the string.  Most probably you did not unwrap an optional value before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have code like this:

```
var aString: String? = "rFchd9DqwE"

let b = "\(aString)"
```

Then the problem is that you are doing it wrong. The "Optional()" bit in your output is telling you that you passed in an optional type instead of a string type.

What you should do is something like this instead:

```
var aString: String? = "rFchd9DqwE"

if let requiredString = aString
{
  let b = "\(requiredString)"
}
```

the "if let" part is called "optional binding". It converts aString from an optional to a regular String object and saves the result in the new constant requiredString. If aString contains a nil, the code inside the braces is skipped.

Another way to do this would be to use the nil coalescing operator:

```
var aString: String? = "rFchd9DqwE"

let b = "\(aString ?? "")"
```

The construct `aString ?? ""` returns the string value of aString if it's not nil, or replaces it with the value after the `??` if it **is** nil. In this case it replaces nil with a blank.

Comment: This is what's known as an "[**XY problem.**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)" Eric D. gave you a solution to the question you asked, but it's the wrong way to go about it.

Comment: @PascalAckermann the problem is really really not solved. You need to in accept the other answer. It is very wrong to be doing this.

Comment: @EricD. No worries. It's easy to fall into traps like this :-) at least you realised what the actual problem is. If you can't get the answer deleted then you could always edit your answer.