# How to get a subString prior iOS 10?

Tags: string, swift3

In swift,I can use subSting() method to get a subString like this:

```
let sessionId = "this is a test"

let index = sessionId.index(sessionId.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)

let prefix = sessionId.substring(to: index)
```

But,today I found the method'availability is iOS 10 and later.How to handle this problem for you guys?

Availability    iOS (10.0 and later), macOS (10.12 and later), tvOS (10.0 and later), watchOS (3.0 and later)

Comment: I Suggest you to put your effort in searching before shooting the question https://stackoverflow.com/a/28182819/2700586

Comment: Thanks ,bro.It's my first question in stackoverflow ,and I am acually a freshman.Your advice help me a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: How to get substring from start to last index of character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28182441/swift-how-to-get-substring-from-start-to-last-index-of-character)